# VisNetwork Clustering by group blocked by icons for nodes

Tags: r, graph, shiny

When I use "cluster by groups" with VisNetwork in shiny, it works fine with regular shapes. However, when I use font awesome icons for groups, I am unable to cluster the network. I have two sets of groups in the data frame for the network. One group, which is used for the icons, groups the nodes.  The other group (called clusters) groups the  node based on their assigned clusters.  The problem is that when I use both, no clustering is performed.

Here is my code:

```
library (igraph)

g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 200, type = "gnm")
dummy <- toVisNetworkData(g)
my.edges <- dummy$edges; my.nodes <- dummy$nodes
my.nodes$group <- ifelse (my.nodes$id < 50, "A", "B")
my.nodes$clusters <- cluster_edge_betweenness((g),weights 
                                          = NULL)$membership
visNetwork(my.nodes, my.edges, 
       height = "700px", width = "100%",
       main = "") %>%
visGroups(groupname = "A", shape = "icon",
        icon = list(code = "f007")) %>%
visGroups(groupname = "B", shape = "icon",
        icon = list(code = "f09d"))%>%
addFontAwesome()%>%
visClusteringByGroup(groups = c(my.nodes$clusters))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visClustering*` are still experimental function, no adapted yet for icons...